# Preventing sprite nodes from "stacking" on top of each other?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to create a shield power up for my iOS spritekit game and instead of refreshing the current shield, it stacks another shield on top. My code:

```
    -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
               ...
    self.shieldIsActive = NO;
               ...
}
    -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
               ...
   else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryLaser | firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryPlasmaShot |firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryProjectile && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryShieldIcon){
        // Projectile OR Plasma Shot Or Laser hits Shield Icon
        ShieldIconNode *shieldIcon = (ShieldIconNode *)secondBody.node;
        ShieldNode *shield = [ShieldNode shieldAtPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-210)];
        [shieldIcon removeFromParent];
        if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryProjectile){
            ProjectileNode *projectile = (ProjectileNode *)firstBody.node;
            [projectile removeFromParent];
        }
        if (!self.shieldIsActive){
            [self addChild:shield];
            self.shieldIsActive = YES;
        }
        // Remove shield after a period of time. BUG: Adds multiple shields if one is already active
        if (self.shieldIsActive){
            SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:ShieldTimer];
            [self runAction:wait completion:^{[shield removeFromParent];}];
            self.shieldIsActive = NO;
```

`...
    }`

Comment: What is your condition? `(Projectile OR Plasma Shot OR Laser AND Shield Icon)`  or `(Projectile OR Plasma Shot OR Laser) AND Shield Icon`

Comment: If the answer is the second proposition then you must encapsulate OR operations before applying AND

Comment: @Exprosul One question (unrelated directly to stacking problem), why don't you use a property for a shield node and when shield is active, unhide it , and when is inactive just hide it (set hidden property to YES) ? Or this does not work for you  (because you can have multiple shield instances at the same time on scene) ?

Comment: @Domsware, Thanks a lot, and ye it was the second proposition. I changed my code and now it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Whirlwind, I didn't really think of hiding and unhiding the shield and I'm not too sure on how to "hide" a property. You have any idea on how I could do it? I'd like to explore my options. Thanks.

Comment: @Exprosul basically you need a property defined like this @property(nonatomic, strong) ShieldNode *shieldNode; I am assuming that ShieldNode class, from example you've posted, is a subclass of SKSpriteNode, so  later in the code (inside didBeginContact, or where ever is needed) you will set shieldNode.hidden property either to YES or NO (hidden / visible). Hope this make sense.

Comment: @Whirlwind I tried using your way and not only did the stacking problem return but several other problems came up too. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Exprosuk I am not sure how stacking can happen if there is only one instance of a shield on the scene... But, if your current code works, then I guess there is no need for changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Domsware pointed out, the bitwise `|` needs to be replaced with logical `||` (and the appropriate parentheses added) in your first `if` statement. Oddly enough, since the `|` operator has a lower precedence than the `==` operator, your `if` statement may have worked as you expected.

Also, you should consider hiding/showing a shield instead of adding/removing shields as Whirlwind suggested.

That said, some thoughts...

1. The conditions for `if (!self.shieldIsActive)` and `if (self.shieldIsActive)` will always be `true` (unless `shieldIsActive` is set somewhere else in the code), which may result in more than one shield in the scene at a time
2. Moving `self.shieldIsAction = NO` into the action's completion block will resolve this issue

and some code...

```
    if (!self.shieldIsActive){
        ShieldNode *shield = [ShieldNode shieldAtPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-210)];
        [self addChild:shield];
        self.shieldIsActive = YES;
        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:ShieldTimer];
        [self runAction:wait completion:^{
            [shield removeFromParent];
            self.shieldIsActive = NO;
        }];
    }
```

Comment: How would I go about changing it so that a new shield would refresh the ShieldTimer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by refresh ShieldTimer.

Comment: After some time, the shield expires. In this case the ShieldTimer is set to 5 seconds. I'm trying to make it so that activating another shield will reset the counter back to 5 seconds. If that makes sense.

Comment: I thought that's what it's doing now.

Comment: What's happening with the current code: Once shield is activated, timer starts. No more shields can be "activated"/stacked. Once the shield timer hits a certain time, in this case 5 seconds, it is deactivated and removed. I want it so that when you gain another shield it refreshes the timer back to 5 seconds.

Comment: The variable `shieldTimer` controls how long the shield will be active. Unless you changed that variable somewhere in your code, the next shield will be active for the same amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Let's replace this condition:

```
else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryLaser | firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryPlasmaShot |firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryProjectile && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryShieldIcon){
```

by this:

```
else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryLaser || firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryPlasmaShot || firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryProjectile ) && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryShieldIcon){
```

Notice the use of `||` instead of `|` for OR operator.